# Logout users and delete cookies if they close browser with PW protected page still open

Tags: php

Haven't been able find something that covers my question - apologies if it is there somewhere. I am building an online library site for a consultant colleague. The site is unrestricted except for one password protected page with special content. It is important to limit the time the PW protected page is left open by registered users. So far, I have been able to auto logout the user from that page after 2 hours and redirect them to another page that explains why they have been logged out, with a link back to the PW page to re-logon if necessary.

I have done that with two PHP snippets found here on Stackoverflow - one to log the user out and one to redirect to a second page - both added to functions.php:

```php
add_filter( 'post_password_expires', 'wpse_custom_post_password_expires' );
function wpse_custom_post_password_expires( $expires ) {
    return time() + 7200; // Expires in 2 hours 
}

header("Refresh:7230; url=https://www.maconsultancy-library.com/redirect-members/");
```

Both work fine in functions.php but interestingly not if I place them in a PHP plugin with shortcode on the PW page.

Problem:
However I discovered that if the user closes the browser with the PW page still open and restricted content available, then reopens the website another day, they are returned to the PW protected content without having to login.

What I would like help with is some PHP I can add to the above code that would prevent the user from creating a "Remember Me" cookie and also delete all existing cookies when they log out.  Is this possible, and can anyone help here?

Many thanks

Comment: Have some identifier in DB that changes every 2h via some cron job. In cookies save this identifier. If it does not match - invalidate user access

Comment: Thanks for your prompt reply.  I will have to research this a bit as have never setup a cron job before

Answer (score 0):

Have a cron job that invalidates all sessions inactive for more than 5 minutes.

On the front end, fire an AJAX request every minute that triggers a script which updates the session to mark it as active.

Comment: Same goes for this offer. I have never used AJAX before either -  so more work to do. But thanks for taking the trouble...